# Android Google Map is not loading after deleting the project

Tags: android, api, google-maps, exception

I implemented a Android Google Map Project that worked fine. But, when I was going to delete a project in my google console, I accidentally deleted my project which i used API for my project. Ever since, in my project, google map is not loading.

Is there anything to do to make it work again?

Here are the errors I'm getting.

> Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from
>   method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb

and

> getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10

and

> Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from
>   method com.google.android.gms.common.kz.a

I don't get a clear exception. Those errors are showing in logcat here and there.

Comment: Agree with @Zach, At the same time, If U deleted ur project in Google console, U will get a mail something like this      
You deleted the project “Project1” on Nov 12, 2015 3:49:12 AM PST. If you still want to delete this project, you don’t need to do anything. The Google Developers Console team will remove your project permanently one week from the time of your request
           If this project shouldn’t be deleted, you must visit the following URL before Nov 19.....     So, "U will get Ur project back" r "Create a new Project"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question but if you deleted the API project on google you can create a new API project in the google console and get a new key. That key needs to be added into your manifest in place of the key that was used for the old api. The line in the manifest looks like below

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_KEY" />
```

Comment: Created a project and copy and pasted the key. still not loading and show those errors in logcat :(

Comment: Hmm, that seems strange. Out of curiosity what is your complileSdkVersion and TargetSdkVersion in build.gradle (Module:App)? Note: If you are using eclipse they would be in the manifest, not the build.gradle. Also try a clean and then build it again.. pry won't do anything but I've seen stranger errors fixed by a clean haha

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make a project in console with changed project name ( if possible) and Change project name also in eclipse or android studio.